# How can we encourage a user to vote for answers and questions?

Tags: discussion

Suppose, you see a user's profile and notice the following pattern: Asked several questions, accepted a few answers but has not upvoted a single answer. The user is probably aware about the voting mechanism as the user's questions, answers to his/her questions have been upvoted by the community.

I think we need to intervene and encourage the user to vote more often but I am unsure as to how to do this.

Any suggestions as to how to do achieve the above? I think diplomatic and gentle approaches are preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, and leaving comments should be the first step.

I think that users should understand that if they don't participate and contribute back, people won't answer their questions as readily.

Comment: It's probably hard for people to see whether a user is 'participating and contributing back,' other than the '#% accept rate,' which is kind of weak. Given that this is a statistics stack, perhaps we can come up with a *better* summary statistic(s) which describe how the user is contributing.

Comment: It takes a while for the user to vote, or for that matter, to do anything on the site. One needs 15 points to vote at all, and that knowledge is layered slowly. Best approach is not to lament the fish not caught, there are many more fish in the ocean than in the fishing pail.